# How to query from one table with conditions from other table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, `slots` and `appointment` below are the tables -

[image]

[image]

I want to query from table `slots` and match some specific conditions from `appointment` table for a particular `doctor_id` and I want to filter out the slot ids which are already in the appointment table on a particular date.

If I input `doctor_id = 1` on `date = '2021-05-09'` then it should give me the available slots that means it should give me information of `slot_id = 3`.

Comment: Please use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)
Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. [ask] [Help] Show what you are able to do. Research before considering asking & reflect research in a question. [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative condition like not in or not exists and join with the second table.

For example something like this:

```
SELECT slot_id 
  FROM slots 
 WHERE doctor_id = ? 
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT slot_id 
                   FROM appointment 
                   WHERE appointment.slot_id   = slots.slot_id 
                     AND appointment.doctor_id = slots.doctor_id 
                     AND date                  = ?)
```

I'm not sure if the same slot can be used by several doctors, if not remove the doctor equality condition.